# How do I suppress the warning from including a library when using knitr in R?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm using knitr to generate HTML output of my work while using R.

The problem is, when I include a library, such as

`library(car)`

my R markdown document includes the warning:

`## Warning: package 'car' was built under R version 2.15.3`

I have tried these solutions, but none work:

````
```{r }
invisible(library(car)
````

and

````
```{r message = FALSE, warnings = FALSE}
````

along with

````
```{r results = 'hide'}
````

and unfortunately none of these options work.

Further options I've tried, and the actual knitr output follow:

[image]
[image]
[image]

How do I suppress the warning from including a library when using knitr in R?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into `?suppressWarnings` ?

Comment: It worked for me (R3.1, OS X 10.9.2, knitr 1.5) without any options. Are you using the `car_2.0-19` package? What R version/etc are you running under?

Comment: I am using R Version 0.98.501, Windows 7.  The warnings are output regardless of package (eg, same situation with, say, `library(psych)`)

Comment: Once again, try `suppressWarnings(library(psych))`

Comment: I don't get the warning message upon loading, so I cannot test it to make sure.  That's why I'm asking you to try it. :)

Comment: It worked.  Ultimately, to avoid seeing the result of including the library, I ended up using:   `suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(library(car)))`

Comment: Odd - using `warning=FALSE, message=FALSE` eliminates those types of startup messages for me.

Comment: The problem boils down to the typo `warnings`, which should be `warning = FALSE`. Also note your R version is unlikely to be 0.98.501, which sounds like an RStudio version. The even better solution is to upgrade R and run `update.packages()`, so that these warnings just go away (they do not exist for no reason).

Answer (score 18):

Set the following chunk options `message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, include=FALSE`.

Answer (score 8):

My preferred approach is

```
suppressMessages(library(foo))
```

and if in doubt also load everything foo Depends on the same way.

A concrete example:

```
R> suppressMessages(library(KernSmooth))
R>
```

and I would invite those suggesting other methods to try on this one too. In this case, `suppressPackageStartupMesssage()` will work too.

Comment: `suppressPackageStartupMessages` may be more targeted for this situation.

Comment: Actually, no: it only suppresses startup messages which use the proper command; most use a straight `cat()` and your suggestion will *not* block those whereas mine does. Been there, done that.

Answer (score 4):

There's a direct way of doing this pretty easily, if you look at `?library`:

```
library(car, quietly = TRUE)
```

It should eliminate most warnings and attachment messages quite nicely. If it doesn't work, add `warn.conflicts = FALSE` too.

Comment: Not uniformly, but that sounds like a reason to shout at M. P. Wand more than anything else; it (should) work fine for this class of warnings, which is around build discrepancies.

Answer (score 1):

Using `message=FALSE` in the chunk options do the job